# How to resolve the error: FlurlHttpException: Call failed with status code 400 (Content-Length can't exceed 10485760 bytes (10MB)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, flurl

When I try to upload a .wav file that is a little over two mins(20 MB) it's thrown an error such as this:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Call failed with status
>   code 400 (Content-Length can't exceed 10485760 bytes (10MB).

Here is the Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SpeakerRecognition
{
    public class IdentificationHelper
    {
        public async Task<string> CreateIdentificationProfile()
        {
            var url = Config.endPoint + "/identificationProfiles";
            return await url
                .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .WithHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Config.key1)
                .PostJsonAsync(new { locale = "en-us" }).ReceiveString();
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteIdentificationProfile(string identificationProfileId)
        {
            var url = Config.endPoint + "/identificationProfiles/" + identificationProfileId;
            var result = await url
               .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
               .WithHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Config.key1)
                .DeleteAsync().ReceiveJson();
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<string> CreateEnrollment(string fileName, string identificationProfileId)
        {
            var enrollmentUrl = Config.endPoint + "/identificationProfiles/" + identificationProfileId + "/enroll";

            var fileBytes = readFileAsBytes(fileName);

            var result = await enrollmentUrl
                .WithHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream")
                .WithHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Config.key1)
                .PostAsync(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes));

            string checkLocation = result.Headers.GetValues("operation-location").FirstOrDefault();
            string checkStatus = "";

            do
            {
                RequestStatus checkResult = await checkLocation
                    .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .WithHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Config.key1)
                    .GetJsonAsync<RequestStatus>();

                checkStatus = checkResult.status;

                Console.WriteLine("Status:" + checkStatus);

                if (checkStatus == "succeeded")
                {
                    if (checkResult.processingResult.enrollmentStatus == "Enrolling") 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "Supply a little more audio, atleast 30 seconds. Currently at: " + 
                                checkResult.processingResult.speechTime);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Done");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for enrollment to finish");
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            } while (checkStatus != "succeeded");

            return ("done");
        }

        public async Task<string> IdentifySpeaker(string fileName, string identificationProfileIds)
        {
            var identificationUrl = Config.endPoint + "/identify?identificationProfileIds=" + identificationProfileIds;

            var fileBytes = readFileAsBytes(fileName);

            var result = await identificationUrl
                .WithHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream")
                .WithHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Config.key1)
                .PostAsync(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes));

            string checkLocation = result.Headers.GetValues("operation-location").FirstOrDefault();
            string checkStatus = "";

            do
            {
                RequestStatus checkResult = await checkLocation
                    .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .WithHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Config.key1)
                    .GetJsonAsync<RequestStatus>();


                // Console.WriteLine("checkResult:" + checkResult);

                checkStatus = checkResult.status;
                Console.WriteLine("Status:" + checkStatus);

                if (checkStatus == "succeeded")
                {
                    return checkResult.processingResult.identifiedProfileId;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for identification to finish");
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            } while (checkStatus != "succeeded"); 

            return ("done");
        }

        private byte[] readFileAsBytes(string fileName)
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        }
    }

    public class RequestStatus
    {
        public string status;
        public DateTime createdDateTime;
        public DateTime lastActionDateTime;

        public ProcessingResult processingResult;
    }

    public class ProcessingResult
    {
        public string enrollmentStatus;
        public float remainingEnrollmentSpeechTime;
        public float speechTime;
        public float enrollmentSpeechTime;

        public string identifiedProfileId;
        public string confidence;
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I am calling this in program.cs:

```
string SeanID = "12345678910";

string enrollmentResult = identificationHelper.CreateEnrollment(@"C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\test.wav", SeanID ).Result; (ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE)
```

How can the code be changed to accept files larger than 10MB as input?

Comment: That error seems pretty obvious, the server isn't accepting a file larger than 10mb.

Comment: @DavidG, that wasn’t my question. The error is obvious. My question was how to change the code fo make it pass files more than 10mb?

Comment: Change the server...

Comment: @DavidG, to what? i am not sure I understand

Comment: Your code _is_ passing files more than 10mb, and the server is not accepting them. The code you posted is acting as the client in this particular exchange. If you wrote the server side of it, that's where you should be looking. If you didn't and this is a 3rd party service, you're out of luck - you need to play by their rules.